How can I emulate an anchor href to the same page with different params but using history.pushState?
I'm working on Grafana and using the Dynamic Text plugin for some custom Datetime picker buttons and links. If I create the buttons as anchor elements with an href that references the same dashboard/URL with different time params (now and to), it works great and doesn't do a full page refresh. I'd like to include other links though, so I've changed the anchors to buttons and added an onclick function. In the onclick function, I can change the URL to have the correct URL params using history.pushState, but the dashboard does not respond to the changed URL. If I use window.location.href = newURL, it will do a full page refresh.
HTML content rendered from Grafana Panel:
{{#each data}}
<button onclick="setDateParams('{{time_from}}','{{time_to}}')">{{button_text}}</button>
{{/each}}

Javascript:
setDateParams = (time_from, time_to) => {
  let url = new URL(window.location);
  url.searchParams.set('from', time_from);
  url.searchParams.set('to', time_to);
  history.pushState(null, null, url);
  return;
}


window.location.hash?

The Navigation API and Chrome web dev docs is meant to replace the History and Location APIs, but is still new enough that it's not yet supported (caniuse, MDN) on Safari or Firefox. Haven't used it yet, but it looks pretty useful.
